# Insert Multiple Line Quote Multiple Times

Tags: shell, vim

I'd like to take this:

```
system_info
show_uptime
drive_space
home_space
```

And paste this:

```
() {

}
```

to end up with this:

```
system_info()
{

}

show_uptime()
{

}

drive_space()
{

}

home_space()
{

}
```

I've tried using visual mode, but to no avail.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://vi.stackexchange.com . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, done. I forgot there's separate stackexchange. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a substitution:

```
:%s/$/() {\r\r}\r
```

Where we substitute each end-of-line `$` in the whole buffer `%` with:

- a pair of parentheses,
- followed by a space,
- followed by an opening brace,
- followed by two line breaks,
- followed by a closing brace,
- followed by a line break.

Or you could simply paste your snippet at the end of each line with `p`.

Comment: Thanks very much :) I tried p, but was getting system_info()\nshow_uptime{\ndrive_space\nhome_space}. This didn't look quite right, since newlines aren't available in comments so I added \n to indicate newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the text to a key and then press that key whenever you want and it will paste the expected text at the end of line.

```
      :nmap \f A()<CR>{<CR><CR>}
```

Put this line in your ~/.vimrc file.

Then, you can keep the cursor on any line and press `\` and `f` immediately one after the other. Cursor will move to the end of the line and the expected text is appended to it.